# IIS 8 Application Initialization HTTP Status Code & SEO

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using the new [Application Initialization](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) feature of IIS 8 for our web application.

Everything is setup correct and the first time we hit the site we are shown startup.html as defined in our web config:

```
  <applicationInitialization
    remapManagedRequestsTo="/startup.html"
    skipManagedModules="true" >
    <add initializationPage="/" />
  </applicationInitialization>
```

The problem is, the startup.html page is returned with HTTP status code 200!

This means for SEO, Google and other search engines may grab the startup.html page instead of the homepage if indexing the site when the application has not been initialized.

Surely the response code should be:

```
503 - the server is temporarily unavailable
```

Is there any way to change the response code of the static HTML page?

(Note: this cannot be done from code as the ASP.NET pipeline would be initalizing)